# How to get previous result in observable with interval?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to get the previous value of observable in Pipe observable with interval. The example is:

```js
const imageStatus = interval(5000)
this.statusSubscription = imageStatus.pipe(
  startWith(0),
  pairwise(),
  switchMap(() => this.settingsService.getImageStatus()),
  tap(res => {
    this.statusMessage = '';
    this.statusError = '';
    if (res.data.message) {
      this.statusError = ''
      this.statusMessage = res.data.message
    }
    if (res.data.error) {
      this.statusMessage = '';
      this.statusError = res.data.error
    }
  }),
  switchMap(res => {
    // here I need to cmpare prevRes and NextRes
    if (res.data.status !== 0) {
      return this.settingsService.getImageList()
    } else {
      return of({})
    }
  })
).subscribe(res => {
  if (res.data) {
    this.imageTableList = new MatTableDataSource(res.data)
  }
})
```

So here I need to know the result of `getImageStatus()` of previous interval iteration. I need to compare previous result and new result in the second switchMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "pairWise" need put after the switchMap, some like

```
interval(5000).pipe(
   startWith(0),
   switchMap(_=>this.settingsService.getImageStatus()),
   tap(res=>{..if you want to do something with the response of getImageStatus...}),
   pairwise(),
   switchMap(([old,value])=>{
      ..here you has in old the before value
      ..and in value the response actual..
      return ....
   })
).subscribe(res=>{
   ...
})
```